# potential resource leak (unassigned Closeable) with a HashMap

Tags: java, memory-leaks, lucene, hashmap

I have one static HashMap for my entire system which contains some object's references; let's call it `myHash`. The objects are only instantiated once I needed them such as

```
private static HashMap<String, lucene.store.Directory> directories;

public static Object getFoo(String key) {
    if (directories == null) {
        directories = new HashMap<String, Directory>();
    }
    if (directories.get(key) == null) {
        directories.put(key, new RAMDirectory());
    }
    return directories.get(key); // warning
}
```

Now, Eclipse is telling me a warning in the return statement:

`Potential resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' may not be closed at this location`

Why is eclipse telling me that?

Comment: Could you provide the `myHash` field declaration?

Comment: And what is `whatever`? If you could turn this into a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem, it would be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Directory` is a `Closeable` that is not closed in the same method it is instantiated in, Eclipse warns you this could create potential resource leaks if not closed somewhere else. In other words, a `Closeable` instance should always be closed somewhere, whatever error could have been thrown.

Here is the usual way to use a `Closeable` in Java 7+:

```
try (Directory dir = new RAMDirectory()) {
    // use dir here, it will be automatically closed at the end of this block.
}
// exception catching omitted
```

In Java 6-:

```
Directory dir = null;
try {
    dir = new RAMDirectory();
    // use dir here, it will be automatically closed in the finally block.
} finally {
    if (dir != null) {
        dir.close(); // exception catching omitted
    }
}
```